# Usage of Parse's Local datastore feature for caching of messages

Tags: android, parse-platform

### Situation

- I write an Android messaging app using Parse.com as back-end
- There's an activity showing list of messages sent to currently logged in user
- User gets *push* from Parse if there is new message for him on the server

I try to accomplish this in two steps:

1. When this activity starts (in its `onCreate` method), I fetch all messages for current user from Parse back-end end store them into local datastore, if there were any messages already in the datastore, they all are removed (unpinned) and the fetched messages are pinned instead
2. Then I ask the local datastore for the messages and with the results I refresh the list of messages (by filling `ArrayList<Message>` variable and calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter using this variable as source of data)

### Why in two steps?

I have it split into two steps, because when the activity is running and user receives from Parse back-end a push that there is/are new message(s) for him, I fetch only the new messages in similar way (but not exactly like) in step 1., and then call the exact same refresh function like in step 2. For this a broadcast receiver handling the pushes is used

### Step 1.

The following code snippet shows how I fetch all messages from server in step 1 in the `onCreate` method of the activity

```
    ParseQuery<Message> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Message.class);
    query.whereEqualTo("recipient", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Message>() {

        @Override
        public void done(final List<Message> messages, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null && messages.size() > 0) {
                ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("messages",
                        new DeleteCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {

                                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("messages",
                                        messages, new SaveCallback() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void done(
                                                    ParseException e) {
                                                for (Message message : messages) {
                                                    if (message.getStatus() == 0) {
                                                        message.setStatus(1);
                                                        message.saveEventually();
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                refreshList();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

    });
```

The part when status is changed from 0 to 1 is to change the message from being *new* to *unread*

For sake of completeness and to document the words written in *Why in two steps?*, this is how I get only the *new* messages in the `onReceive` of the broadcast receiver processing the pushes from Parse back-end

### Broadcast receiver snippet

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ParseQuery<Message> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Message.class);
        query.whereEqualTo("recipient", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        query.whereEqualTo("status", 0);
        query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Message>() {

            @Override
            public void done(final List<Message> messages, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null && messages.size() > 0) {

                    ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("messages", messages,
                            new SaveCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    for (Message message : messages) {
                                        message.setStatus(1);
                                        message.saveEventually();

                                    }
                                    refreshList();
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

### Step 2. The `refreshList` function

```
private void refreshList() {
    ParseQuery<Message> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Message.class);
    query.fromPin("messages");
    query.whereEqualTo("recipient", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Message>() {

        @Override
        public void done(final List<Message> messages, ParseException e) {
            items.clear();
            for (Message m : messages) {
                items.add(m);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

### Other variables

```
ArrayList<Message> items;
MessageArrayAdapter adapter;
```

Where `MessageArrayAdapter` just extends ArrayAdapter

### Why do I need to use the local datastore at all?

- The activity can exist for quite long time
- ... and the user can receive new messages when the activity is running
- I don't want to ask the server every time there is new message for all messages
- I know I could ask just for the new ones and add them to the `items` when it is member variable of the activity where all this happening. In such case, I didn't have to use the local datastore at all
- The reason for using it is that in the future I plan to move the *fetch all messages* from the activity completely - e.g. to start of whole application or maybe to service fetching the messages on periodic basis

## Is this acceptable way of solving this problem?

Comment: You use the local datastore to save messages in case the user navigates away from your app, logs out, loses internet connection, etc.  If you relied only on your cloud records, then the app wouldn't be able to read any messages.  At least with local datastore, you can cache things locally